# Profile dependent properties - maven JEE6

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to use a environment specific property (ftp connection). And to do so I've tried to do the following in my parent pom:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>dev</id>
      <properties>
        <env>development</env>
      </properties>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault> <!-- use dev profile by default -->
      </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>prod</id>
      <properties>
        <env>production</env>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>test</id>
      <properties>
        <env>test</env>
      </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

and do the following in my "child" pom:

```
<build>
    <filters>
      <filter>profiles/${env}/config.properties</filter>
    </filters>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

In that child project I've created a folder "profiles" with subfolders "development", "test" and "production". They all have one file: config.properties with ftp.host=something.

In my child project I've created a .properties file in my src/main/resources folder with the following content:
ftp.base.host=${ftp.host}

I thought this can be done but it seems it can't since, when I'm getting the property, I'm always getting the literal string "${ftp.host}" instead of "something" (defined in the config.properties)..

Has anyone got any idea what I'm doing wrong? Other approaches than this one are also ok..

Comment: Are you sure you're running the profile ie mvn clean install -P dev etc. Also, perhaps "env" is a keyword? Try changing the name of the property to something a bit longer.

Comment: I guess I've forgot something.. (kind of new to doing things like that). I just start my application server (jBoss) from eclipse. But I guess I will have to define somewhere that I want to deploy with the dev profile?

Comment: Also note the following: I've defined the profiles in my parent (called parent). The ear that I deploy is called "webservice" (subproject of parent) and I defined the filter in my ACL project (sub project of webservice).

Comment: Alright.. When I run the command from the commandline and put the generated ear in jBoss it's working. Any idea how I can configure this in Eclipse?

Comment: Yes in eclipse you need to do 'run as' then select 'run configurations' double click the 'm2 maven build' option, create a new run configuration. In the goals box put "clean install" and in the profiles box put 'dev' (or whatever)

Comment: ok... I must be getting crazy. It's working in Eclipse right now but I actually didn't do anything :). But thanks!